# overriding Page Render method

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SharePoint 2010 >> Editing Output HTML >> Issues with page or master page render override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980477/sharepoint-2010-editing-output-html-issues-with-page-or-master-page-render)

I need to override Render method of the page and make some actions with output html before rendering it. But i get some strange issue when trying to perform even simplest actions.
For debug proposes I've added code like this:

```
protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["test"] == "test")
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        base.Render(new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb)));

        writer.Write(sb.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        base.Render(writer);
    }
}
```

And now if there is ?test=test in the URL the output HTML is broken. The response HTML starts with:

```
VM-SP\administrator<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var _spUserId=1;
//]]>
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html ...
```

If there no ?test=test in the URL the response HTML starts with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html ...
```

'VM-SP\administrator' is the name of the current user. Why the output is different? What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Does the page reference a master page? Is this the simplest possible page, or are there various controls on the page? Something else may have written to the output before you did.

Comment: It's not the simplest page. It has controls and references master page.

Comment: I suggest you try the simplest first, then complicate things a little at a time. You'll find which complication causes the problem.

Comment: _spUserId is one of the SharePoint javascript variables - something related to SharePoint wrote it into the page. Is this script block present somewhere in the page when there is no "test=test" in QueryString?

Comment: Igor, yes it is. If there is no 'test=test' this code is placed inside the Sharepoint user menu. Where user can signout or sign in using different account. And it should be there.